# How to know in which task an ansible play failed when launched using AWX API?

Tags: error-handling, ansible, ansible-awx

I intend to launch ansible jobs on AWX using AWX api and get a call back from the ansible playbook to be informed about the result of the play.

To do so I'm using the `/api/v2/job_templates/<job-template-id>/launch/` with some extra_vars in the body to pass parameters to my play.

```
{
    "extra_vars": {
        "target": "w.x.y.z",  (put here a real IP)
        "directory_name_1": "dir1",
        "directory_name_2": "dir2",
        "file_name": "file1"  (or "subdir/file1" to make it fails)
    }
}
```

I've also configured a webhook notification in the job-template with the default customization: `{{ job_metadata }}`

I've put here the play I'm using which is super simple, it creates 2 directories and one file in the first directory.

```
- hosts: "{{ target }}"
  name: fbplay
  tasks:
    - name: Create dummy directory 1
      file:
        path: "{{directory_name_1}}"
        state: directory
    - name: Create dummy directory 2
      file:
        path: "{{directory_name_2}}"
        state: directory
    - name: Create dummy file in directory
      file:
        path: "{{directory_name_1}}/{{file_name}}"
        state: touch
        mode: u=rw,g=r,o=r
```

All of this work great and in case of error 4 tasks will be executed on the target machine:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
TASK [Create dummy directory 1] ************************************************
TASK [Create dummy directory 2] ************************************************
TASK [Create dummy file in directory] ******************************************
```

...but here is my question with regard to error handling: How can I indicate in the call back which task failed in case of error ?

In fact I can know if the play failed or not getting, in case of success:

```
  "hosts": {
    "w.x.y.z": {
      "failed": false,
      "changed": 1,
      "dark": 0,
      "failures": 0,
      "ok": 4,
      "processed": 1,
      "skipped": 0,
      "rescued": 0,
      "ignored": 0
    }
  }
```

and in case of failure:

```
  "hosts": {
    "w.x.y.z": {
      "failed": true,
      "changed": 0,
      "dark": 0,
      "failures": 1,
      "ok": 3,
      "processed": 1,
      "skipped": 0,
      "rescued": 0,
      "ignored": 0
    }
  }
```

But I cannot get the exact task that failed (in this case the last one by passing a filename containing a sub-directory that does not exist for example).

I'm a newbie on AWX & ansible and I'm fighting with what I thought would be a relatively simple point... so any hints or ideas is welcome.

Thx beforehand.

Comment: You could also have several tasks that failed for different hosts at different points in your playbook (e.g. host1 fail on task1, host2 on task3 and host3 succeed all of them). I'm afraid you cannot have this precise information without looking at the task log.

Comment: @Zeitounator, yes you're perfectly right, in fact I had forgotten to mentioned that in my main use cases I'll have most of the time only one {{ target }} and thus will run the playbook on one host only.

Comment: Actually I think I found something that might be useful: https://ara.readthedocs.io/en/stable-0.x/faq.html#organized-task-results. I'm not sure it provides API though to query the result but at least it looks that it can display the result at the task level of any playbook being ran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case it helps someone, I actually confirm that [ARA](https://github.com/ansible-community/ara) does what I was looking for above which is to display if using its web client (or provide through an API) exactly which task failed in each playbook you ran.

Answer (score 0):

ARA does an excellent job for analyzing awx-runs, but it has to be set up on the AWX-server (the host running the AWX instance), if I understand correctly.

A workaroud would be to use the `awx` commandline interface ( see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towercli/index.html and * ):

`watch --color 'awx --conf.host https://awx.site --conf.username my.user --conf.password "my_super_secret" -k -f human job_events list --job 3232445 --event "runner_on_failed" --filter "stdout"'`

One could also **sroll the API** for different "?event=runner_on_failed", like:

https://your.awx.site/api/v2/jobs/3232445/job_events/?event=runner_on_failed

Or other "filters" like:

`awx --conf.host https://awx.site --conf.username my.user --conf.password "my_supersecret" -k -f human job_events list --job 3232445 --event "runner_on_unreachable" --filter "*" >/tmp/tmp`

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towercli/output.html#human-readable-tabular-formatting
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towercli/reference.html#awx-job-events-list

* (not to confuse with `awx-cli/tower-cli` - I think they are different)